# Extended Date type says function not found

Tags: typescript

I found this gist on useful date extensions: https://gist.github.com/weslleih/b6e7628416a052963349494747aed659

When I try to use the functions I get a runtime error saying:

> TypeError: x.isToday is not a function

It works if I import the extensions in the file were i use them like this:

> import 'src/date.extensions';

The is seems to hacky. Because how does the next person know that this needs to be imported in order to make the date extension method work.

Does anyone have a better solution?

(or maybe this is the wrong approach. I'am used to C# were extending methods is done frequently)

Answer (score 1):

Method extension really isn't recommended in Typescript and Javascript, my recommendation is to make an exported function that takes a date and returns a boolean, something like this:

```
const isToday = (date: Date): boolean => {
  const now = new Date();
  const inputDay = date.getDay();
  const inputMonth = date.getMonth();
  const inputYear = date.getFullYear();

  const nowDay = now.getDay();
  const nowMonth = now.getMonth();
  const nowYear = now.getFullYear();
  return (
    nowDay === inputDay && nowMonth === inputMonth && nowYear === inputYear
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you know why it is not recommended? I think it nicer/easier to read e.g. date.addDay() and date.isToday() than addDay(date) and isToday(date).